# Firebase Analytics screen view event not loging screen name every time

Tags: java, android, firebase-analytics

I've setup a fonction to log screen envents from my android app.

```
FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

if (screenName.length() > 36) {
   bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName.substring(0, 36));
} else {
   bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName);
}

bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, activity.getClass().getSimpleName());
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);
```

However, depending on the class loging the event, the screen name is not event part of the event sent to Google.

Here's the event loged when working :
`Logging event: origin=app,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=app, engagement_time_msec(_et)=15735, ga_previous_class(_pc)=SlideMenu, ga_previous_id(_pi)=1601424672890182561, ga_screen_class(_sc)=SlideMenu, ga_screen_id(_si)=1601424672890182562, ga_screen(_sn)=Recommandations}]`

And when not working :
`Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=SlideMenu, ga_previous_id(_pi)=1601424672890182562, ga_previous_screen(_pn)=Recommandations, ga_screen_class(_sc)=AffichageContent, ga_screen_id(_si)=1601424672890182563}]`

As you can see in the 2d line, the `ga_screen(_sn)` field is missing.

From what I've seen, it seems that the only class not loging the screen name is `AffichageContent` but I don't know if it's from the class itself or because this activity is started by a previous one.

I've loged the `bundle.getString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME)` and it's value before loging the event is the right one.

Thank's !

Comment: @NamrataBagerwal Hi, unfortunately no, I ran out of ideas to try to debug this ...